# Connecting to AWS RDS using eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, amazon-web-services, rds

I am facing the following error everytime I try to connect to the AWS RDS (MySQL) database instance from AWS explorer for eclipse. I new to using AWS, so I am not able decipher what is going wrong!

Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to Amazon RDS DB: uswest-mysql-easycheckin - US West (Oregon). (Error: Access denied for user 'admin'@'c-68-81-114-246.hsd1.pa.comcast.net' (using password: YES))
Access denied for user 'admin'@'c-68-81-114-246.hsd1.pa.comcast.net' (using password: YES)
Error creating JDBC Connection connection to Amazon RDS DB: uswest-mysql-easycheckin - US West (Oregon). (Error: Access denied for user 'admin'@'c-68-81-114-246.hsd1.pa.comcast.net' (using password: YES))
Access denied for user 'admin'@'c-68-81-114-246.hsd1.pa.comcast.net' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a problem with your security groups? "By default, network access is turned off to a DB instance." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html

Comment: Highly unlikely, since this message appears to be in the standard format *generated by* a MySQL Server when a non-existent username/host combination or invalid password is used.  Security groups being insufficiently permissive wouldn't allow the connection to be established, and that connectiob would be necessary for this error to be returned.